# How to set years on X axis as integer in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, types, charts, data-visualization

I don't know why but when I run ggplot stacked area chart, years on the x-axis are doubles like 2012.5.... I set them as integer but still have this issue. Any solution?

```
df$Year <- as.integer(df$Year)

order <- df %>% filter(Year ==max(df$Year) ) %>% arrange(desc(Sales)) %>% select(Category)
df$Category <- factor(df$Category, levels = order$Category)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Sales, fill = Category)) +
  geom_area()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the breaks to use with `scale_x_continuous()`.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Sales, fill = Category)) +
  geom_area() + scale_x_continuous(breaks=2010:2020)
```

To make it more dynamic and automatically choose the limits base on your data, use:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Sales, fill = Category)) +
  geom_area() + scale_x_continuous(breaks=min(df$Year):max(df$Year))
```

And if you don't want to show every year you can use `seq()` to just have every Nth year. E.g. for every third year:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Sales, fill = Category)) +
  geom_area() + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(min(df$Year),max(df$Year),3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(df$year), max(df$year), 1))` per below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~year, ~sales, ~category,
  2020, 4, "a",
  2021, 5, "a",
  2022, 5, "a",
  2020, 4, "b",
  2021, 5, "b",
  2022, 5, "b"
  ) 

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, sales, fill = category)) +
  geom_area() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(df$year), max(df$year), 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>